# How to create email list in exchange 2010

Tags: email, exchange-2010, mailbox, distribution-lists

I would like to create some kind of email list in exchange 2010. From user side, it will look as something like this when they create message:

Group_1

Group_2

Group_3

When user click on the list above (for example Group_1), it will select all email in that group.

I have found to 2 ways to achieve this:

1. Using mailbox address list. However, this method will require user to manually select the emails in the list (or select all).
2. Using distribution group. However, this method will create new email address (example: group1@company.com). I prefer not to do this since spam mail will be sent to everyone)

Is there any other method, especially that does not require creating new email. Tq.

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding, if you want to email to such list, it should have an email address, and mailbox address list is used for finding users, not to email directly. I’m afraid a distribution group is a better choice.

For a distribution group, it could be managed as internal only, it would allow only senders in your organization to send messages to the group. If someone outside of your organization sends an email message to this group, it will be rejected.